# Is there a way to avoid a new line while using `end=`

Tags: python, python-3.5

I've just started using python and I'm creating a simple program that will ask whoever the user is a question and then from the text file I will extract a specific line and print that line and along with the line - at the end I will add their answer. here's the code.

```
    question = input("do you want to print the line")
    if "yes" in question:
        print(open("tp.txt").readlines()[:10][-1],end=question)
```

The issue is that `,end=question)` puts the users answer on a new line. I know that `end=` is the same as `\n`. So I'm just wondering is there a way or an alternative to stop 'end=' from automatically creating a new line?

```
 print(open("tp.txt").readlines()[:10][-1],
```

is the way I open and read a specific line from the file
since its a 'nice' shortcut to do than rather do`with open (filename.txt,'r') as f:`

Comment: No: there is no way to "read a specific line".  You can do: `with open('file.txt') as f: lines = f.readlines()` and then do `line_n = lines[n]`, but the whole file will be in memory. This is because files are fundamentally **sequential** and also *not line based*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the lines returned by `readlines()` contain the ending newline:

```
$ echo 'a
> b
> c
> ' > test_file.txt
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('test_file.txt') as f:
...     print(f.readlines())
... 
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', '\n']
```

See the `\n`? Note the difference bewteen:

```
>>> print('a\n')
a

>>>
```

And:

```
>>> print('a')
a
>>>
```

So you want to remove that:

```
>>> with open('test_file.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line.rstrip('\n'), end='<something>')
... 
a<something>b<something>c<something><something>>>>
```

Comment: so does `.rstrip` have to be any where specific

Comment: @j.doe What do you mean? `rstrip` removed characters from the end of the string (the `r` stands for *right*). If you want to remove from the beginning of the string use `lstrip` (where `l` stands for *left*). If you want to remove from both the beginning and ending than use `strip`.  But given that the newline will always be at the right I think it's better to use `rstrip`.

Comment: oh ok i severely misunderstood i get it now. out of curiosity  what Does `with` and `as` mean

Comment: @j.doe The `with` statement was introduced in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). Basically it's a way to handle resources. In the case of files what it does is to automatically close the file at the end of the block, so that you don't have to worry about calling `.close()`, but depending on the type of resource it can do other things. The `as` is just used to assign a name to the value being handled.